# Help displaying java characters in different languages

Tags: java, http, internationalization

I'm sending a request to a web service, and the response that I receive could be in any language: English, French, Arabic, Japanese, etc.

I'm having a problem displaying the different languages correctly, however.  For example, I am receiving:

```
translation: ä½ å¥½
```

Instead of:

```
translation: 你好
```

I'm guessing that I'm not encoding correctly in my HTTP Request/Response.  Can someone tell me what I may be doing wrong?  Here is the code where I receive the HTTP response:

```
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        InputStream responseData = connection.openInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[20000];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = responseData.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        System.out.println(new String(baos.toByteArray()));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Refer to listing 4, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0409_tong/0409_tong.html#listing4

Answer (score 1):

In the end when you print, try

`System.out.println(new String(baos.toByteArray(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));`

Answer (score 1):

```
new String(baos.toByteArray());
```

is going to interpret the byte[] with your platform's default character set.  From [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5b%5d%29):

> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the platform's default charset.

Those bytes need to be interpreted by a decoder which is compatible with the character set the server is sending you.  Often this is specified in the HTTP `Content-type` header.

Answer (score 1):

I think You should use the method `toString(String charsetName)` of `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Something like this:

```
System.out.println(baos.toString("UTF-8"));
```

Of course you have to use the **same encoding** on both the server and the client.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use InputStreamReader, and OutputStreamWriter. Those classes let you specify the encoding. 
For example:

```
Writer out   = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "UTF-8"));
out.write(something);
```

Answer (score -1):

in

```
System.out.println(new String(baos.toByteArray()))
```

you need to supply the correct Charset to `new String(byte bytes[], Charset charset)`.

You need to know which Charset to use (i.e. it should be sent with the response).
Default is UTF-8, but this does not cover Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew etc.

Comment: well, UTF-8 *does* cover all these languages, but it's not the default.

Comment: You are absolutely right, i should have refreshed my rusty knowledge about unicode before answering. Sorry for that.